# How to set the javamail path and classpath in windows-64bit "Home Premium"

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have installed java on Windows (64-bit). My question is: how do I install Javamail my PC? I used this way to create classpath `%classpath%;c:\....` ect. but does not work still. I get the have error

> The import javax.mail cannot be resolved

Answer (score 1):

To install Javamail you should have a look at the [ReadMe](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail145readme-1562609.html). Which states:

> Note that the JavaMail API requires the JavaBeans(TM) Activation
>   Framework package to be installed as well if you're using JDK 1.5 or
>   earlier.  Download the latest version of the JavaBeans Activation
>   Framework from
>
> ```
> http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/index-jsp-136939.html
> ```
>
> and install it in a suitable location.

And

> 1. Unzip the javamail1_4_5.zip archive.
>       (You may have already done this.)
> 2. Set your CLASSPATH to include the "mail.jar" file obtained from 
>       the download, as well as the current directory.
>
>    Assuming you unzipped javamail1_4_5.zip in c:\download the
>       following would work:
>
>    set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;c:\download\javamail-1.4.5\mail.jar;.
>
>    Also, if you're using JDK 1.5 or earlier, include the
>      "activation.jar" file that you obtained from downloading the
>      JavaBeans Activation Framework, in your CLASSPATH.
>
>    set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;c:\download\activation\activation.jar
> 3. Go to the demo directory
> 4. Compile any demo using your Java compiler. For example:
>
>    javac msgshow.java
> 5. Run the demo. The '-' option lists the required and optional
>       command-line options to successfully run any demo. For example:
>
>    java msgshow -
>
>    lists the available options. And
>
>    java msgshow -T imap -H  -U  -P  -f INBOX 5
>
>    uses the IMAP protocol to display message number 5 from your INBOX.