# how can I use javamail api with jdk8 in windows8.1. I am using cmd for compling Java files

Tags: java, jrecorder

I have download an external package of mailing i.e javamail1.4.7 
but I get fail to work with it .
I am using win8.1 and jdk8. 
I set path in cmd like this --- d:\jdk8\javamail\demo>path d:\jdk8\bin;d:\jdk\javamail\mail.jar;
and then I try to compile a demo file which is given with javamail api. 
it gives me 48 errors 
and very first error is javax.mail does not exist. 
.
please help me how can i use javamail api from jdk.
.

Comment: You have to add the java mail to the classpath, not to the Path.

Comment: The PATH for finding executables has nothing to do with the ClassPath.  I suggest you use an IDE to set up your environment.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10161448/how-to-set-the-javamail-path-and-classpath-in-windows-64bit-home-premium

Comment: sir I have already try to set CLASSPATH like --- CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;d:\jdk8\javamail\mail.jre . but cmd give error that CLASSPATH is not recognize asinternal or external command.

Comment: mail.jre should be **mail.jar**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the classpath variable incorrectly. Unlike in a Unix shell, cmd requires you to use the `set` command to set variables.
This is the proper way to set `CLASSPATH`:

```
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;d:\jdk8\javamail\mail.jar
```

Comment: mail.jre should be **mail.jar**

Comment: Thanks. I just copied and edited the line in the original post. I should have read it more closely.

Comment: thank you a lot .... now my project is compiling but when I try to run it, It shows an error: could not find or load main class SendMail. Actually I have to need an mail sending frame so I make a java class i.e SendMail.java